# Java disambiguation of unary prefix operators

Tags: java, tokenize, unary-operator

How does the Java parser handle ambiguous unary operators?

For example, assuming you had `int x` declared somewhere, `+--x` is perfectly valid code. `---x` is theoretically valid as well, but the compiler throws an error. Likewise, `+~~~~~~+--x` is accepted, but `~~~~~~++--x` is not even though they could both be parsed into valid expressions.

As far as I can tell, the grammar is ambiguous, so it must be handled during tokenization, but I can't find anything that explains it.

Comment: Apart from the "curious minds want to know" aspect - can you think of any practical situation in which you would need to know this? In other words - does this ever matter? Did you come across something like this?

Comment: @Floris I'm working on a tool that outputs Java source code, so yes it is important.

Comment: From some of your comments it seems your question might actually be something along the lines of "How does the Java compiler detect ambiguous unary operators".  Am I correct, or have I missed the point entirely?

Comment: @ajm Technically everyone one of the expressions I posted is ambiguous. Presumably the parser uses something like Maximal Munch, but I can't find that mentioned anywhere.

Comment: OK, I think I see your point now.  Unless someone comes along with knowledge of this stuff it might be worth digging into the source code of OpenJDK and trying to find out what it does that way.  Potentially a lot of effort, but you would hopefully get a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Stephen P has implied, unary operators are grouped right to left in Java, which means those expressions are ambiguous as different operators could group to the right.  See [Section 15.15 of the Java 7 spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15) for the rules on unary operators.

**EDIT**

To some extent I think you've answered your own question.  It seems that expressions that are ambiguous, such as ---x, cause compile errors, as the compiler doesn't know what you want it to do.  In these cases it is the programmer that needs to resolve the ambiguity by making the expression more specific - e.g. by adding parentheses to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: I already read that section, hence the questions. Anyway, it looks like an issue with the tokenizer, and I couldn't find anything that explained that part.

Answer (score 3):

`---x` is ambiguous because it could mean `-(--x)` or `--(-x)` or `-(-(-x))` while `+--x` is unambiguous because there is no `+-(-x)` possible.

Comment: `+(-(-x))` would be possible though.